# How to get the content of the file in variable in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I am uploading files that I need to attach to email via office365 API.

What I need is the content of the file in a variable WITHOUT storing/saving the file, how can I do that?

```
foreach ($request->filesToUpload as $file) {
    $originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();//working
    $content = $file->getContent();//<- I need this, but not working
    //$this->addAttachment($content, $originalName) //logic for later
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Access the contents of the file like so:

```
$content = file_get_contents(Input::file('nameAttribute')->getRealPath());
```

or in other words inside that loop

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file->getRealPath());
```

Get the real path with object methods, and you may interact with it like any other file.

Comment: Okay let me try file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));

Comment: Yes, it's working. Inside the loop, like $fileContents = file_get_contents($file->getRealPath());

Answer (score 0):

Waqas Bukhary,
You get that result, beucause, `getContent` is not a method of uploadedFiles, check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html).
But you have the path, so you can always read the content, like:

```
$path = $file->path();
$handle = fopen($path, 'r');
$content = fread($handle, filesize($path);
fclose($handle);
```

You can also use the Request File method if you know the name of the file field, check it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#files).